# JqueryUI tooltip appear elsewhere

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, jquery-ui

i have two view styles of a single page, one "**Normal view"** another " **Full screen**"

In **normal view the Jquery tools tip appears fine**  as shown in below screenshot
[image]

But if i press a "full-screen" button then the **tool-tip does not change its position**, it still appear in the same position as it was appearing in the "Normal view" .
Below screen shot is in   Full-screen mode...

[image]
Below is the code i used :

```
       <script>
   $(function() {
     $(".tooltip").tooltip({
       position: {
         my: "center bottom-20",
         at: "center top",
         using: function( position, feedback ) {
           $( this ).css( position );
           $( "<div>" )
             .addClass( "arrow" )
             .addClass( feedback.vertical )
             .addClass( feedback.horizontal )
             .appendTo( this );
         }
       }
     });
   });
   </script>
   <style>
   .ui-tooltip, .arrow:after {
     background: black;
     border: 2px solid white;
   }
   .ui-tooltip {
     padding: 10px 20px;
     color: white;
     border-radius: 20px;
     font: bold 14pt "Calibri", Sans-Serif;  
     text-transform: capitalize;
     box-shadow: 0 0 7px black;
   }
   .arrow {
     width: 70px;
     height: 16px;
     overflow: hidden;
     position: absolute;
     left: 50%;
     margin-left: -35px;
     bottom: -16px;
   }
   .arrow.top {
     top: -16px;
     bottom: auto;
   }
   .arrow.left {
     left: 20%;
   }
   .arrow:after {
     content: "";
     position: absolute;
     left: 20px;
     top: -20px;
     width: 25px;
     height: 25px;
     box-shadow: 6px 5px 9px -9px black;
     -webkit-transform: rotate(45deg);
     -moz-transform: rotate(45deg);
     -ms-transform: rotate(45deg);
     -o-transform: rotate(45deg);
     tranform: rotate(45deg);
   }
   .arrow.top:after {
     bottom: -20px;
     top: auto;
   }
   </style>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think your toopltip has position:absolute, which causes it to be in the same place as it used to be. Please try changing it to "relative" position in CSS, and it should work.

Comment: Still the same problem, i added this css ,whereever i was using `.tooltiop` like this `<img style="position:relative;" class="tooltip" src="`     . But still the same issue..